# Is it okay to not have a rogue in my party in Dragon Age 2?

Tags: dragon-age-2

I know that one's supposed to have all three varieties of members in a party, but the thing is: I am a mage but I also like to have Anders and Merill along. For the remaining slot, I usually prefer Fenris. So, thats three mages and one warrior. The battles were always satisfying with the above party but I just want to know if there would be any advantange if there's a rogue except for the fact that they can detect traps and unlock locks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't underestimate the lockpick ability: there are a *ton* of chests that require lockpicking skill.

If you're familiar with *Dragon Age: Origins*, you probably remember that the rogue was by far the most powerful class to the point of excessiveness: a single, high-level rogue could outmatch 3 warriors or mages. Of course, a *melee* rogue companion (like Zevran) was next to useless because you couldn't position him for backstabbing unless you were directly controlling him.

*Dragon Age II* smoothed the curves, as it were, when it comes to rogues. They're not clearly overpowered, but they still have a lot of bang for very little buck. And it's easier to outsource melee roguing to Isabela since backstabbing in DA2 is auto-positioned.

So you can forgo the use of Isabela (the only melee rogue you can get), Varric, and Sebastian (the two archers you get), but you're probably making the game a little harder for yourself.

Balance aside, *Dragon Age II* made great strides in trying to encourage use of all your companions:

- All characters, whether they're in your party or not, gain the same amount of experience
- Every companion has a specific armor set and can't use anything else, making it unnecessary to maintain several sets of armor
- Every character has side quests, dialogue, and flavor associated with them
- There are several quests along the way that require the use of specific characters
- It's pretty easy to find a place where you can swap out party members

So feel free to mix it up every now and then.

Comment: I've tried Isabella for a couple of times...but usually she'll be the first to fall in a battle...maybe I need to refine her tactics or something

Comment: @Uday Isabela isn't the strongest companion (but certainly more useful than an AI Zevran from DA:O); Varric on the other hand is pretty awesome.

Comment: More importantly, your rogues will be the only ones capable of opening most locked chests, especially later in the game -- unless you're willing to drastically cripple another character's build by spending a lot of points into their cunning rather than strength or magic.